# Sails.js res.redirect() don't support proxyHost

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have config

```
proxyHost: 'http://localhost:1337/1.0',
```

and routes

```
'GET /1.0/subscriptions/success': 'SubscriptionController.success',
```

In controller,

```
res.redirect('/subscriptions/success');
```

Browser is redirect to URL "http://localhost:1337/subscriptions/success", I expect it will redirect to "http://localhost:1337/1.0/subscriptions/success".

Where can I make config to this?

Comment: Have you tried `res.redirect(sails.getBaseurl() + '/subscriptions/success');`?

Comment: Yes, I know this is work. I just wonder have any configure can do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what the `proxyHost` setting is for.  It is solely to allow `sails.getBaseurl()` to return the correct base URL for when your site is being proxied (e.g. by Nginx) so that the public-facing host/port is different from the host/port exposed on the server.  It doesn't affect the URLs of the routes that are bound in your app, nor does it affect the action of `res.redirect`.

If you want to prefix all of your routes with `/1.0`, you can use the `prefix` setting in `config/blueprints` (documented [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints#?properties)).  You'll still need to include the prefix manually when doing redirects, but you won't need to actually nest your controllers under a `/1.0` folder.

Comment: Thanks, you help me too much. :)